# Prevent NSTimer firing delays in background app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I'm working on a macOS app (let's call it the "display app") that displays a clock and other data, which is controlled by another app (the "control app") on the same machine via a TCP connection. I have noticed that when the display app is idle for some time (> 60 sec.) and then schedules an NSTimer (with a .2 second interval), it takes a *very* long time before the timer fires for the first time (in the range of 6-10 seconds, sometimes longer.) That happens mostly when the display app is not frontmost (because the control app is.) Once the timer fired for the first time, it works as expected (with some small, expected delays in the timer) for some time.

But when the timer is running for a long time (more than 5 minutes), there are similar extreme delays between firing (also 6-10 seconds.) It looks like manually scheduling the timer with

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

postpones the problem a bit (using `[NSTimer scheduledTimer...]` makes that problem appear sooner than when manually adding it to the runloop.)

This causes a lot of trouble because the clock is not updating during that time.

I assume this happens because macOS considers the display app "idle" or "inactive" in some way.

Is there a way to prevent, control, or circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: There are, essentially, no timing guarantees using `NSTimer` (the documentation is pretty clear on this point). Consider using Grand Central Dispatch as your timing mechanism, like [Repeat](https://medium.com/@danielemargutti/the-secret-world-of-nstimer-708f508c9eb)

Comment: This may be [App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html). You can try making the display app call `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] beginActivityWithOptions:NSActivityUserInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep reason:@"whatever"];`.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks, that was exactly the issue. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thanks, I know that timers aren't guaranteed to be precise, but the issue here was clearly beyond normal timer lag - the time differences amount to 5000%. The problem was indeed caused by App Nap.

Comment: @JamesBucanek What an "enlightening" comment - yes, it's pretty well understood that there are no timing guarantees, but there's a difference between few milliseconds and 10 flippin seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html). The display app can do the following to avoid napping:

```
id activity = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] beginActivityWithOptions:NSActivityUserInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep reason:@"whatever"];
```

When it can allow napping again, you should do:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] endActivity:activity];
```